# How to block (column?) paste in vim

Tags: vim

how can i paste something on multiple lines?

i'm trying to achieve the same as:
In an existing text, I can <C-v>jjjjj<S-I>HelloWorld<CR>
to have HelloWorld inserted in 5-rows

but instead of typing HelloWorld I'd like to get the text from a register.
i want to first yank HelloWorld then insert it in 5 lines.

Comment: @sotto - StackOverflow is for programming questions. Your question will probably get migrated to SuperUser.com which is a better forum for general computer usage questions.

Comment: @Oded
vim is a programming tool like a VS. How can it be unrelated?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you are in insert mode, you can press `Ctrl-R` followed by the letter for the buffer you wish to paste. Then just press Escape as usual and it will be block inserted as normal.

Comment: So, as per Doug's answer below, this would be, after yanking the text you want to fill down, `<C-V>jjI<C-R>"<ESC>` (assuming you do a normal yank, without specifying a buffer).

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you have the following in a vim buffer:

```
1|  Do the dishes
2|  Get milk
3|  Take out the trash
```

and you want to insert `[ ]` at the start of each line, so that it becomes:

```
1|  [ ] Do the dishes
2|  [ ] Get milk
3|  [ ] Take out the trash
```

---

1. go to column one of row one
2. press `CTRL + V` (block select)
3. press `j` two times (to row three). now the first column of lines one, two, and three are selected
4. press `I` (shift + i - capital "i") - this is "block insert mode"
5. type `[ ]`
6. press `esc` (escape)
7. text will be inserted on each row

Answer (score 3):

You could use a macro to do this, like `qq0Pjq4@q`

`qq` starts a macro with the name `q`

`0` goes to the beginning of the line and `P` pastes the yanked content before the cursor

`j` goes down one line and `q` ends the macro

`4@q` repeats the `q` macro 4 times